# Foreign key over three tables

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database for a web survey application. I have been studying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5858666/1707938) but I want to add additional tables to store other set of choices of the respondents. In particular I have one table for cities and one for foreign countries. Yet I like the idea of storing the answer to any question in a single `unique_option_id` column, which can unequivocally identify the choice of one the three option tables.

[image]

What I then need is some sort of table (which I call `option`) to maintain a column `unique_option_id` which is the `PIK` of country, city or multiple choice. Yet a foreign key can't reference to multiple tables. So I am not sure how I should implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think what you are want is a "composite foreign key"

Basically your forigen key will be contained in one column however be made up of 
PKI1 + PKI2 + PKI3, from the 3 other tables,  It will depend on the database as to how exactly this is supported.

Hope that will help point you in the right direction.