# Dynamic conditions

Tags: c#, sql, conditional-statements

I am looking for a way to create conditions dynamically in a C#/winform front end with a SQL back end.  Right now it is a dynamically generated question and answer form.  The database has one table with the questions and another with the possible answers.  I add a label with the question and a combo box with the answers.  I have all of that working.  My issue is I can't come up with a way to create conditions.  An example being if someone answers "Yes" to question 2 then they have to answer 2a and 2b or if they answer "No" then 2a and 2b become "N/A".  How do I create that link?  Can I store an if statement in the database and pass it into the program?

Edit:It is more of a survey.  There are no right or wrong answers.

Comment: Try adding a new bit(boolean) column on the answers table, so you can even check if the given answer is correct on the database.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  There are no right now wrong answers.  It is more like a survey.  The answers they give will be stored when they are done.

Comment: [**Survey Database Design**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5858666/342740), ***This is just a table design example for survey but I think you can learn a lot from this*** and it already takes into consideration when a question is a condition for another, as you can see on the dependent field. Even tough its not for MSSQL the design still applies with minor if no changes at all.

Comment: You could add 2 fields to each question that lets it say it is dependant on another question and what the answer should be for it to show

Comment: That link was what I wanted.  Using that design I adapted it to what I needed and now I have dynamic conditions working.  Thank you.